# Get iCloud emails to Gmail

Tags: gmail, icloud

I'm trying to opposite thing most websites describes. I'm using GMail as my major app and iCloud account as addition to owned iPad. I'm trying to add iCloud (me.com) account to Gmail. But either I'm missing something or this is not possible.

I've sereached the net ot get iCloud / me.com [account details](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4864). Then I followed usual way, I've been using to add my previous three external e-mail accounts, I'm checking via my Gmail. I thought, that adding fourth -- iCloud / me.com -- shouldn't bring any problems. Turned out, I was wrong.

I've added all account details (server, login, password, port, SSL etc.) into "Add new account" page. In response I got server error with following description:

```
Missing +OK response upon connecting to the server:
* OK [CAPABILITY st11p00mm-discream009 1O59 IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR AUTH=ATOKEN 
AUTH=PLAIN] iSCREAM ready to rumble (1O59:32462) st11p00mm-discream009
```

Whoa! Does it means, that Gmail uses non-standard headers when getting e-mail from external account or it is not sending something, it should send, and therefore getting e-mails from iCloud / me.com account in Gmail is... impossible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gmail seems to be rather strict about the +OK response; what you're seeing is nonstandard but innocent silliness like "iSCREAM ready to rumble" getting rejected.

So, the short answer is: No, you will not be able to use Gmail as an IMAP client for your iCloud account (so far as I know).

If your primary concern is sending and receiving using your @me.com email address, you could forward all your iCloud emails to your Gmail address (http://support.apple.com/kb/ph2642) and set Gmail up to send from your @me.com address (http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370).  If you do this, try to send using Apple's SMTP servers (in the second link, scroll down to "If you choose to send mail through another domain's SMTP servers:" and follow the directions).  The only drawback with this approach is that whatever you do in Gmail to iCloud messages isn't mirrored back in your iCloud account itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Drawback mentioned by you isn't a problem (at least for me). If I setup forwarding all e-mails iCloud --> GMail, there will be noting to mirror on iCloud side, as all e-mails will be permanently moved to Gmail (if I'm getting you right). Cheers...